# Cast String to T in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, jvm

my following code is my approach on simplifying my Applications properties:

```
class Preference<T>(private val key: String, private val defaultValue: T) : ReadWriteProperty<AppPreferences, T> {

    override fun getValue(thisRef: AppPreferences, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        return ((properties.getProperty(key) ?: defaultValue) as T)
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: AppPreferences, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        properties.setProperty(key, value.toString())
        saveProperties()
    }
}
//endregion

//region Variables
var isAuthenticationEnabled by Preference("is_authentication_needed", false)
var timeoutSeconds by Preference("timeout_seconds", 1000)
var adminKey by Preference("admin_key", "")
//endregion
```

But i need a way of converting the Properties, which are always read as strings to T. This approach doesn't work for obvious reasons, but any attempt to convert e.g. with when(T) or else will result in the error "Cannot use 'T' as reified type parameter. Use a class instead".
So my question: How can I convert this string to T inside the getValue method?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let whoever is creating a `Preference` tell you how to convert `T` to/from `String`. Add `(T) -> String` and `(String) -> T` as constructor parameters.

```
class Preference<T>(
    private val key: String,
    private val defaultValue: T,
    private val convertToString: (T) -> String,
    private val convertFromString: (String) -> T
) : ReadWriteProperty<AppPreferences, T> {

    override fun getValue(thisRef: AppPreferences, property: KProperty<*>): T {
        return convertFromString(properties.getProperty(key)) ?: defaultValue
    }

    override fun setValue(thisRef: AppPreferences, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        properties.setProperty(key, convertToString(value))
        saveProperties()
    }
}
```

Then, you can create functions for preferences of a specific type - `String`, `Int`, `Boolean` etc. These methods will create an instance of `Preference` and pass in the `(T) -> String` and `(String) -> T` parameters, and return that instance.

```
fun preference(key: String, defaultValue: String) = Preference(
    key, defaultValue, { it }, { it }
)

fun preference(key: String, defaultValue: Int) = Preference(
    key, defaultValue, Int::toString, String::toInt
)

fun preference(key: String, defaultValue: Boolean) = Preference(
    key, defaultValue, Boolean::toString, String::toBoolean
)
```